# Is it possible to solve this system of nonhomogeneous DE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I am following this [ARTICLE](http://www.math.utah.edu/~gustafso/2250systems-de.pdf) on solving the differential equations. Take a closer look at page 580, chapter "11.7 Nonhomogeneous Linear Systems" - Theorem 23.

Follwing this work, brought me to the following equation
$$x_1(t)=e^{At}x_{1.0}+e^{At}\int_{t_0}^te^{-Ar}F_1(r)dr$$
Now my problem here is that $F_1(r)$ is in fact a function of $x(t)$ for example $$F(r)=F_0\sin(x(r))$$ where $x(r)$ under the integral is the same as $x(t)$ - is the function that I am looking for!

I assume there is no way around that? Any other ideas how to solve a system

$$\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 
\dot x\\ 
\dot y
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
O &I \\ 
 M^-1 K&M^-1B 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 
\dot x\\ 
\dot y
\end{pmatrix}+\binom{\vec 0}{M^-1\vec F(t)}$$ where you can assume that all the matrices M, K, B are known.

Comment: In the system $F$ depends on $t$, while in the integral form you say it depends on $x$.